# Changing field type with mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I am looking at the sample_mflix database for MongoDB and it seems that this database is somewhat inconsistent with the data types. For example I have gone through and changed all of the 'year' fields from 'string' (type: 1) to number. But when I execute the following:

```
db.movies.find({"year": { "$not": { "$type": 16} } });
```

I see the data has changed but it is still not 16 as a type (32-bit integer). When I query using the 'type of' operator it comes back as 'number'. The type 'number' doesn't seem to be listed in the documentation for types. I would like to convert all types for this field to be the same and I would like to have them all integer or all 'number'. How do I change the type to be 16 like the rest of the rows? or how do I change the rows that are not 16 to be 'number', whatever that is?

Comment: From this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/index.html#available-types): `$type` supports the `number` _alias_, which will match against the following BSON types: `double`, `32-bit integer`, `64-bit integer` and `decimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.movies.find().forEach(function(ch)
  {
         db.movies.update({ "_id":ch._id}, {"$set" :  { "year":parseInt(ch.year)} });
  });
```

So here you can use parseInt() to convert string to int type.